Jenkins pipeline fails on git ls-remote command with error can't run program "nohup" in Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 1224365
Jenkins pipeline failed on command:`curl -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: ****' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data-raw 'items.find(

[2024-12-08T18:21:14.465Z]     {
[2024-12-08T18:21:14.465Z]         "repo":{"$eq":"art-generic-dev-local"},
[2024-12-08T18:21:14.465Z]         "path":{"$match":"int.game.amatic/*"},
[2024-12-08T18:21:14.465Z]         "name":{"$nmatch":"*-tests.zip"}
[2024-12-08T18:21:14.465Z]         "name":{"$nmatch":"*.pdf"}
[2024-12-08T18:21:14.465Z]     }Error is same, can't run program "nohup". After several restart of jenkins agents, It cleare on that stage and on different stage it fails: git ls-remote --tags | grep '2cb8d2db1980450cceaf4111a0459fa62edebda1' || true— Identify Git tags<1sCannot run program "nohup" (in directory "/mnt/jenkins/workspace/servicedir"): error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 1224283, exit value: 1`

Added on jenkins master -Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork stopped jenkins service and started.
Now oit looks like this:
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true \
                      -Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork "

Tried disconnecting and reconnecting agent to master from UI.
Loged in jenkins agent as a jenkins user and tried from workspace dir:
Which nohup and It showed /usr/bin/nohup.
Service dirs in workspace have all 755 permissions.
Restarted jenkins agent service and jenkins master.
Then tried to add debugging steps in my groovy jenkins pipeline, like,
sh "which nohup"
     sh "ls -ld /mnt/jenkins/workspace/form_CASINO_Amatic_release_6.0.0"
     sh "echo $PATH"

and all of them fails with same error.
 echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin — Shell Script <1s Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "/mnt/jenkins/workspace/servicedir"): error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 1224365, exit value: 1
Observing jenkins console output logs,
I see
java.io.IOException: error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 1224365, exit value: 1
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from ip-10-3-3-94.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.3.3.94:49196
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1003)
        at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:1121)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:506)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:180)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:134)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:329)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:323)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.methodCall(LoggingInvoker.java:105)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:110)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CastBlock$ContinuationImpl.cast(CastBlock.java:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:147)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:17)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:49)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:180)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:423)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:295)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$wrap$4(CpsVmExecutorService.java:140)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:53)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$categoryThreadFactory$0(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 0e4b091d-0f04-4ada-87fa-3c617e0b0e47
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "/mnt/jenkins/workspace/servicedir"): error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 1224365, exit value: 1

Update coreutils and It's up to date. Recently jenkins agents were patched by sysops, may they have broken something? Since pipelien worked okay for a long time.
I think to turn of directory recursive deletion after failing pipeline and investigate in that directory.
My college recommended downgrading java from 21 to 17.
What to try next? How to debug?

This looks more like a question for https://devops.stackexchange.com/
